# CSS to align image for each rss feed from external site

Tags: css, image, css-float

How could I show the thumbnail images align properly on the top left for each news feed?

[image: rss]

this is the codes for each item's feed, I couldn't alter the format below because it's was rss feed from external site

```
<style>
img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;       
}
.feed-item-title{
    clear:right;
 }
</style>


<div class="feed-item">
<h3 class="feed-item-title">
    <a href="" target="_blank">Rihanna Hug During VMA Show</a>
</h3>

<div class="feed-item-body">
    Former couple share embrace on night when both won major awards.<br />By Hosten
    <a href="">
    <img type="photo" src="281x211.jpg" />
    </a>
    <br />
</div>

</div>
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use floats you should clear them.

```
.feed-item-body:after{
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Later Edit: Few extra changes added, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sttej/) is the working example.

Comment: thanks, by this way the rss thumbnail and title will show in top down instead of left right in each item's feed.